# Puzzling Increase in Rep Points Today

Tags: discussion, reputation

Today, I gained +60 reputation points.  The majority of these gains were from numerous questions/answers I wrote quite a while back.

I did not have this type of gain in any day of the past few weeks, especially not from such a wide variety of questions/answers I wrote.

It also just so happens that today I joined Stack Exchange Academia, asked a question there, and answered one question here on Stack Exchange Physics.  Does this have anything to do with my unexpected gain recently?  Does the website make my questions/answers more accessible if I show more activity?

Comment: Please wait a day whether these upvotes disappear again, you may have been the target of [serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/263383).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens to me from time to time.

I suspect when someone sees a question or answer of yours that they like they will then look at your other questions and answers, and they may upvote some of them as well. I doubt is due to the SE bumping your posts because as far as I know having one of your questions or answers upvoted has no effect on your other questions and answers.

As ACuriousMind mentions in a comment, If someone gives you lots of upvotes in a short space of time the SE is likely to conclude this looks a suspicious voting pattern and may cancel the upvotes. If they have disappeared tomorrow that is probably what happened.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of one person going through my profile and doing this.  Good to know.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this is a good opportunity to:

1. encourage users to vote. You decide what are quality posts on Phys.SE and what are not. Currently (September 2017) Phys.SE gets around 200 posts and 500 votes per day.
2. urge voters to vote according to content, not the author, nor because of what others voted, etc. In particular, only voting on posts from a single poster (known as [serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/209806)) is frowned upon, and may lead to moderator actions.